# Automatically Remove Line When Committing in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am working on a project in IntelliJ which I push to GitHub. However, there is one line that contains sensitive information that I do not want anyone to see. Is there a feature or extension that will omit that line when committing?

Comment: Do you really mean "when pushing" or do you mean "when committing"?

Comment: I suppose "when committing". I'll change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of an IntelliJ feature or extension like what you're asking for. (And I don't know that there isn't one.) But

- you could do what you're asking with a git pre-commit hook. There is an example of that in [How does this pre-commit hook fix trailing whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677425/how-does-this-pre-commit-hook-fix-trailing-whitespace). That would have the advantage of working even if you committed from the command line, or if a teammate wanted to use a different editor.
- even better, move the sensitive information into an environment variable or a configuration file (and .gitignore it), so that you don't have to change the code at all.